# Alternative to glass fireplace door?

Tags: fireplace, fire-hazard

My rental apartment has a fireplace, which we use often. This fireplace lacks a glass door. On nights when we have used the fireplace, we leave the flue open until the morning, and when we get up, the entire level is freezing. As it's a rental, I can't just install a glass door myself.

I bought [this fireplace cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009L2GQKQ), but I find that it only helps so much. I am thinking of building a supplemental heat barrier, with the following layers (from closest to furthest from fire):

- radiant foil barrier
- fiberglass insulation (no vapor retardants)
- plywood

I would cut the fiberglass to the size of the plywood, then take a slightly larger piece of foil and wrap it around, then tack and tape it in place. I would lean this over the fire retardant fireplace cover that I already have.

Would this be safe? My concern is that, if an ember managed to rekindle, I wouldn't want to create a fire hazard. One possibility is to use a spray-on fire retardant, or just to wrap the entire piece of plywood in foil before attaching the fiberglass and outer foil layers.

Alternatively, and preferably, is there a commercially available product I could use instead?

Comment: If the flue is open I am guessing because a small fire is still burning.  If so you can't put anything made of wood or insulation remotely close.  Be easier to set an alarm and close the flue.

Comment: Wood fireplaces don't usually have doors. Inserts do--but not actual fireplaces. As DMoore states, the solution is to close the damper when you can. Burn less, or start earlier.

Comment: Thank you! How long do we have to wait before closing the flue? We have been waiting 12 hours, which makes us very cold!